# Error: Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to retrieve a USER from my database using the ID in the WHERE clause.  However I am receiving an error and my program is failing.

This is the error I'm receiving when I run my program:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-19) 
JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component CustomerServiceBeanImpl 
for method public abstract package.name.entity.ICustomer 
package.name.bean.CustomerServiceBean.getCustomerById(long): 
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Parameter value [19533] did not match expected type [package.name.entity.User (n/a)]
```

*Note: [19533] is a test value I used.*

This is the method that is having the error in the CustomerServiceBeanImpl.java:

```
@Override
public Customer getCustomerById (final long id)
{
    return Customer.getById (this.em, id);
}
```

This is the method that's being called by the component CustomerServiceBeanImpl:

```
public static Customer getById (final EntityManager em, final long id)
{
    for (final Customer c : em.createNamedQuery ("Customer.getById", Customer.class)
    .setParameter ("id", id).setMaxResults (1).getResultList ())
    {
        return c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The name query is this:

```
@NamedQuery (name = "Customer.getById", 
query = "SELECT o FROM gnf.Customer o WHERE o.user = :id")
```

In the Customer.java class itself the relevant column is this one:

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name = "user_id")
private User         user;
```

Doing a quick check of my ERD the "id" column in my "customer" table has a data type of BIGINT.  However I'm not sure if that matters.  (PostgreSQL database by the way.)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The WHERE clause in your named query seems to be the problem. The attribute user in your Customer.class is of type User and your query expects it to be a type compatible to long.

...
Parameter value [19533] did not match expected type [package.name.entity.User ...

So if you need more help on this it would be great to see the complete entities User and Customer.

Comment: That would make sense.  I'm going to try to fix it and if it works I'll mark yours as the answer.  Otherwise I'll probably share more information.

Comment: In general the query is linked to the class name (case sensitive) and property names of the Java class, not the table name and table column names. When there is a table containing a foreign key caused by a `@OneToOne` relation or something similar, the parameter in the query needs to get set to the **object**, **not** its id.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because in your database the parameter will be a @oneToOne object and you have to call the id inside the Object so you have to give the query as following :

"select user from User user where user.customer.id=:param"